# create ipa without RoboVM in a project libgdx

Tags: libgdx, ios, android-studio, build-process

I am creating an application with libgdx , and I wish I could produce an IPA without using RoboVM , because since version 1.9 became a fee . I saw on the original documentation that you can do with the gradlew.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-the-project

command:

```
gradlew ios:createIPA
```

but I saw that still requires robovm . you can create an IPA without robovm ? or if there is a plugin that makes the IPA.

I use Android studio (IntelliJ)

Thank you

Comment: 1) This question has some answers over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646963/create-ipa-without-robovm-in-a-project-libgdx 2) It is now the future (2017!) and LibGDX has a [MOE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/multi-os-engine) backend

Comment: I think you can use multi-os engine ,Unlike robovm it seems free and have support for libgdx [Documention](https://doc.multi-os-engine.org/multi-os-engine/9_game/1_libgdx/libgdx.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was asked, answered and accepted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646963/create-ipa-without-robovm-in-a-project-libgdx). Cross-posting is not allowed on StackExchange sites. Please chose the site that will give you the best/most answers, and ask only there.